# my smarty got unknown tag , but it is a legal tag

Tags: smarty, smarty3

currently i change smarty 2 -> version 3

but after i change got problem as below.

```
SmartyCompilerException: Syntax Error in template 
"/home/test/engine/mobile9/template/t_footer.tpl" on line 28 
"{php}" unknown tag "php" in /home/test/engine/modules/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 617
```

after that i check smarty 3 documentations. it shown {php} is valid operator.

Answer (score 4):

Check the documentation [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl):

> IMPORTANT NOTICE
>
> {php} tags are deprecated from Smarty, and should not be used. Put
>   your PHP logic in PHP scripts or plugin functions instead. Note
>
> As of Smarty 3.1 the {php} tags are only available from SmartyBC.

If you're using Smarty 3.0x, it should work. If you're using Smarty 3.1, you have to install the [SmartyBC class](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl) (Backwards Compatibility Wrapper) for the use of the `{php}`-Tag.

But where possible try to follow Smartys advice: Put PHP logic in PHP scripts, and not into the Smarty templates.

Comment: thx a lot, coz this page will be remove soon, just temporary there. better include this pluggin. thx

Comment: == {php} Tag ==
The {php} tag is disabled by default. The use of {php} tags is
deprecated. It can be enabled with $smarty->allow_php_tag=true.

But if you scatter PHP code which belongs together into several
{php} tags it may not work any longer.
this is wat i found in smarty official sites. mayb this is one of the solutions.