# I want to write PHP code for a Smarty .tpl file

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I want to write PHP code for a Smarty .tpl file. But it is giving me the following error:

> Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "./templates/register.tpl" on line 185 "{php}" unknown tag "php" <--
>       thrown in
>       /opt/lampp/htdocs/Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 185

When I Google it, I realized it's deprecated and not recommended to use. What should I do now? I want to show drop down with the security question in it.

Comment: Checkout - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208215/my-smarty-got-unknown-tag-but-it-is-a-legal-tag

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Smary is or how it is used, but what I get from documentation is that {php} is deprecated.

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl

Answer (score 0):

to echo the $foo variable in tpl file just past `{$foo}`

Answer (score 0):

You should make changes in smarty_securoty.php and make

public $allow_php_tag = false; to

public $allow_php_tag = true;

it allow PHP Code in .tpl file

Comment: @krishna do u knw location of smarty_security.php file.??

Comment: I used to put in library.folder.Like   libraries\general\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_security.php

Comment: i write it in php file and store it in variable. and use this variable in .tpl file. it works. thank u for your help..